# X object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python-2.7

I am reading [Dive into python 2](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/special_class_methods.html) and I am having troubles with this example:

```
class FileInfo(dict):

   def __init__(self, filename = None):
      self['name'] = filename

   def __getitem__(self, key):
     return self.data[key]


if __name__ == '__main__':
   f = FileInfo('pixies.mp3')
   print f.__getitem__('name')
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FileInfo.py", line 12, in <module>
     print f.__getitem__('name')
  File "FileInfo.py", line 7, in __getitem__
     return self.data[key]
AttributeError: 'FileInfo' object has no attribute 'data'
```

I'm using Python2.7

**EDIT**
Actually, this code works fine:

```
class FileInfo(dict):

  def __init__(self, filename = None):
     dict.__setitem__(self, 'name', filename)

  def __getitem__(self, key):
     return dict.__getitem__(self, key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   f = FileInfo('pixies.mp3')
   print f.__getitem__('name')
```

But I would like why the another code doesn't work (Is Dive into Python 2 outdated?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complaining that your FileInfo doesn't have a data attribute. You can solve it by adding "self.data=XXX" under your **init** function. Depending on what you need. You need to initialze all attributes under you **init**

Comment: But my `FileInfo` class inherit from `dict`, doesn't it? I suppose that `dict` have a `data` attribute and I can use it.